# How do you understand "he is divine and is not at all human"

Tags: meaning, phrases, sentence

Sentence:

> When God became flesh, he is divine, and is not at all human.

What do you think is the meaning of this sentence? i am editing some religious translation writing. i just want to make sure if it is understandable and the meaning is same as source text.

Comment: This is a question about religion, and that is often even more illogical than English.

Comment: This question probably belongs on [Biblical Hermeneutics SE](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/).  (Someone please kick it there.)

Comment: @HotLicks It definitely does not belong on either Biblical hermeneutics, since this quote does not come from a biblical text, or Christianity SE, since there is no source for the quote. It would be quickly closed on either site in its current format.

Comment: Why did you change **I** (capital) to **i**? What is the source? What research did you do to make this question on-topic? Please read the [link](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/translation/infohttp://english.stackexchange.com/tags/translation/info) carefully.

Comment: the literal translation of source is "When God became flesh,  he has divinity,and has no humanity. i just want to know if it is translated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

From: https://www.gci.org/Jesus/dualnature

"That Jesus is both God and human is a mystery beyond our limited experience. Yet no other explanation upholds all that Scripture says about Jesus Christ. Understanding this essential truth is more than an intellectual exercise. It involves appreciating the great depths of God's love for us.

Jesus, conceived by the Holy Spirit in the womb of a woman (Matthew 1:20), was the union of God and humankind for the express purpose of providing a Savior for us (verse 21). This Savior would have a vital and unique quality—he would be Immanuel, which means 'God with us' (verses 22-23). He was indeed fully God and yet in an amazing, glorious way, he was 'with us' by being fully one of us.

Jesus is fully God and fully human."

**[Please note that I have no opinion on this matter, except that the author of the example sentence in the OP appears to contradict this example answer.]**

Comment: thank you very much. i just want to make sure whether you can get the same meaning as source text. and i am glad you can understand it. so we can keep the translation as it is. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: limits.  "human" means "limited".  The reason for this is because the word "human" is being contrasted (compared, with a focus on differences instead of similarities) from being divine.  So, understanding this sentence just requires a knowledge of how the divine is different from humanity.

The clear instance, which most people probably assume, is that the sentence refers to Jesus (as a significant number of people recognize God became a man, as recorded by [John 1:14](https://biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john+1:14) which says he "became flesh and lived among" people).  If that is the case, this sentence directly opposes the belief that Jesus was fully human, which is a common belief supported by [Hebrews 4:15](http://biblehub.com/hebrews/4-15.htm)).  However, there may be some other examples of God as flesh, such as [Genesis 32:24,30](https://biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+32:24,30) where God is recognized to be in another form.  Some people also identify other examples, such as Melchizedek or the archangel Michael, as being God.  Some of those claims may be disputed by even more people, but the point being made here is not trying to focus on religious accuracy.  The point is simply that, without further context, the most obvious person that the sentence may refer to would be Jesus (as taught by Christianity), but there may be others as well.

Although the Jewish scriptures say that God created mankind in God's own image, clearly God is recognized as being different than mankind.  The most famous examples are God's great power, lifespan, and knowledge, and perfection.

In contrast to God, humanness may refer to the limits we have.  We are not omnipotent (completely powerful, able to do anything we want), immortal (ignoring the concept of the "afterlife", the "life after death", I'm just saying that the lives we are living right now do end), nor are we omniscient (all-knowing... there are some things I don't know).  People are also imperfect.  Usually that statement refers to moral insufficiently, although a person who makes a mistake by providing an incorrect answer to a math problem could also be viewed as being "imperfect".

Those are probably the most famous examples.  There are other differences, such as God being immutable (God does not mutate/change), whereas humans may grow (by learning and gaining maturity).  God is often credited as being superior (and even "infinite") in other areas that humans may be more limited in, such as patience.

The sentence's reference to humanity ("being human") is highlighting the differences from divinity ("being God"), since the sentence is basically claiming that the fleshy existence is not human.  The differences between God and human can be summarized as God being unlimited.  I'm summarizing these differences by saying that being "human" refers to limits, since these limits are what makes humans notably different from God.  However, that is a slight over-simplification, since not all differences can be simply described as humans being limited.  For instance, the growth that a human experiences is actually a human doing something good that an immutable God doesn't do.

In the end, the sentence doesn't actually specify which differences (between divinity and humanity) the sentence refers to.  Perhaps the sentence refers to all such differences, or perhaps the sentence was used in a context that was intended to refer to only some such difference.

Note, also, this answer was largely written from the perspective of a Christian background.  I would expect that people with different religious backgrounds might have some different viewpoints about some aspects, such as what the word "divine" means/implies.

Comment: thank you very much. i just want to make sure whether you can get the same meaning as source text. and i am glad you can understand it. so we can keep the translation as it is. thanks again.